# get rid of partial submodule status

Tags: git, repository, git-submodules

I had a directory tree which contained a git repository (which I did not think of at that time).  Then in a father two dirs up I did a `git init` and tried to add everything in that tree.  It did not add the files in the subdir which already had a `.git` directory, but I still didn't notice that and just added this directory as well.  (I'm not sure what exactly I typed, but at the time it seemed to me that everything now was done, though I still stayed a little curious why that adding at the top didn't add everything; but I dropped the thought then.)

Now I noticed that cloning that outer repository does not check out the files in the inner repository.  After some investigation I found that the inner repository seems to be a submodule of the outer, but somehow not a proper one.

Things like `git submodule` or `git status` or `git log` never mention that inner repository but trying to add a file from the inner repository into the outer repository always states:  `fatal: Path 'path/to/innerRepository/somefile' is in submodule 'path/to/innerRepository'`, even If I remove the inner `.git` directory.

What I would like to achieve now is get rid of the information that the directory of the inner repository (and all its contents) is part of another repository.  I want to forget the old repository and check the files into the new repository.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing the inner .git folder won't be enough to convince the parent repo that a certain path isn't a submodule.

`path/to/innerRepository` is probably recorded in the index the the parent repo as a [special entry (mode 160000)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19354410/6309)

Try

```
git submodule deinit path/to/innerRepository
```

(it should fail if you don't have .gitmodules)

And:

```
git rm --cached path/to/innerRepository  # no trailing slash
```

The last command should make your parent repo "forget" about that submodule.

Comment: I read about `deinit` somewhere else before asking here; sorry I didn't mention.  The `deinit` line you proposed results in an error:  `error: pathspec 'deinit' did not match any file(s) known to git.`  Looks like my git version (1.7.9.5) is too old to know that command?

Comment: @Alfe yes, upgrading would be nice. But don't forget this command *will* fail anyway if you don't have a `.gitmodules` file. The most important command is the `git rm --cached`: that is the one which mattters here.

Comment: Will that `git rm` actually remove any files?  Since they aren't "known" to git, I assume it won't remove files, right?

Comment: @Alfe no! `git rm --cached` only remove from the index, not from your disk. and remember: no trailing slash. `git rm --cached path/to/innerRepository`

Comment: @Alfe did you try it? Did it work? Is the status gone?

Comment: Perfect, thanks a lot!  After removing the `.git` dir of the inner repository (I reinstalled it, so I had to remove it again), and `git add path/to/innerRepository` I now have a lot of "new" files in the outer repository :-)